# Improving performance of loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a basic loop that drops a value into a cell on one sheet, calculates the entire workbook, and returns a couple of values to another sheet. The values being returned are contingent upon the entire workbook being calculated each time. Initially, this worked great, but now that I have many more formulas to calculate the loop is way too slow. Is there a common solution to this problem? Below is the code I have that works, but is way too slow.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Dim wsRepository As Worksheet
Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wsRepository = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Repository")
Set wsInput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")

For i = 4 To 2004



           'add investment amount
           wsInput.Range("N13").Value = wsRepository.Range("B" & i).Value


           'copy back amounts
           wsRepository.Range("E" & i).Value = wsInput.Range("U12").Value

           wsRepository.Range("C" & i).Value = wsInput.Range("V12").Value

           wsRepository.Range("D" & i).Value = wsInput.Range("W12").Value


    Next i

wsInput.Activate
```

Comment: Too little information. Please provide the code of your loop and the information on which part works the longest e.g. the calculation of the workbook etc.

Comment: If the code is working and you would like to improve its performance, you can also post your code at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In any case without posting the code itself it is hard to offer any valuable help..

Answer (score 0):

Try bracketing your invocation of *Calculate* with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.SCreenUpdating = True`. That should improve your performance dramatically as EXCEL stops trying to redraw the screen on evaluation of every new value.

Comment: This is a comment rather than answer. `ScreenUpdating` will make some improvement but the loop/calculate routine is where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide any additional input it will be hard to provide you with any suggestions.

In general VBA performance can be improved in multiple ways. Here are most of them:
http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/